# Django Mixins Search Function

Tags: python, django

I have a working FBV search function that look like this:

```
def search(request):
    query_string = ''
    found_entries = None
    if ('q' in request.GET) and request.GET['q'].strip():
        query_string = request.GET['q']

        entry_query_study = get_query(query_string, ['title', 'category', 'service', 'subject', 'industry', 'description', 'keywords', 'objective',])
        entry_query_page = get_query(query_string, ['title', 'url', 'category', 'keywords',])

        found_entries_study = Study.objects.filter(entry_query_study).order_by('title')
        found_entries_page = Page.objects.filter(entry_query_page).order_by('title')

        found_entries = list(chain(found_entries_page, found_entries_study))

    return render_to_response('search-results.html',
                         { 'query_string': query_string, 'found_entries': found_entries },
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I have an unworking CBV search function with a mixin that looks like this:

```
class SearchMixin(object):
    def get_queryset(self):
        query_string = ''
        found_entries = None
        if ('q' in request.GET) and request.GET['q'].strip():
            query_string = request.GET['q']

            entry_query_study = get_query(query_string, ['title', 'category', 'service', 'subject', 'industry', 'description', 'keywords', 'objective',])
            entry_query_page = get_query(query_string, ['title', 'url', 'category', 'keywords',])

            found_entries_study = Study.objects.filter(entry_query_study).order_by('title')
            found_entries_page = Page.objects.filter(entry_query_page).order_by('title')

            found_entries = list(chain(found_entries_page, found_entries_study))

        return render_to_response('search-results.html',
                         { 'query_string': query_string, 'found_entries': found_entries },
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))

class SearchResultsView(SearchMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = "search-results.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchResultsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["page"] = Page.objects.filter(get_query(query_string, ['title', 'url', 'category', 'keywords',])).order_by('title')
        context["study"] = Study.objects.filter(get_query(query_string, ['title', 'category', 'service', 'subject', 'industry', 'description', 'keywords', 'objective',])).order_by('title')
        return context
```

I get the error query_string is not defined.  I could just put all the search logic into get_context_data, but then what is the point of a SearchMixin?  What I am trying to do is this:  I have a search box that searched two models page and study.  It works fine with a FBV, but I'm trying to use a class based view so that I add context['page'] and context['study'] so that in my template I can use them in if statements for displaying the results.  To do the processing inside the template is a no-no according to the wonderful book Two Scoops of Django.

What I'm having trouble understanding, is how to access the data in the mixin's get_queryset.  Otherwise I'm just repeating myself.  Maybe I have the whole structure wrong, obviously I need some help.  I've read tons of resources but I am having trouble fitting it all together.

I want to essentially implement the same functionality that is in the FBV, into the CBV, as well as add the context data that I mentioned to allow me to do things like `{% if site %}{{ site.title }}{% endif %}` or `{% if study %}{{ study.title }}{% endif %}` etc.

For example, I'm pretty sure render_to_response() doesn't belong at the end of get_queryset(), but what else would I put there, and where would I put render_to_response?  I need help translating the FBV to a CBV so I can do the context data stuff I talked about.

I think maybe MultipleObjectMixin may do the job but have no clue how to use it and can't find any examples.  If someone has one, please do share as it may solve the issue.

If someone can help me out, correct my code, give me an example, point my in the right direction, etc.  It would be most appreciated.

ASIDE:  I've had a lot of trouble ever since I started to get an exact understanding of how to use get_queryset and get_context_data.  I understand get_context_data returns the context so you can use variables and such in templates.  But I don't see how to use get_queryset.  Or how it connects to get_context_data.

Essentially, how can I return two objects from get_queryset.  And where does that return to?  How can I return page and study from get_queryset and then add the contexts I want in get_context_data and then finally call render_to_response.  I just don't see how these all connect let alone how to return 2 objects from get_queryset.

Some help steering me in the right direction would help a lot.  Examples are the biggest help.

Comment: `get_queryset` won't get called in a `TemplateView` unless you override the `dispatch` method or call it in the `get_context_data` method.

Comment: I can call get_queryset like that, but what I want to do is be able to pass the query_string and found_entries like in the FBV along with the context['page'] and context['study'] so that I can use if statements to check if a results is one or the other.  This is a search form btw.

Comment: You should probably take a look at `ListView`.

Comment: I know ListView, I've used it many times, my issue is I want to use two objects with get_queryset, and I want to add each of those to context so I can decipher between them within a form.  For example I combine them for my search results, but I want to take the results in the template and use the context to act on results from each model differently.

Comment: You could override `get_queryset` to return a list containing the results from your two models. It accepts anything that is iterable.

Comment: It does return a list that i used itertools to chain from two lists.  The trouble is adding those lists to the context in the CBV.  I'm confused on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution you can follow using CBV could be something like this:

```
 class SearchResultsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "search-results.html"

    def find_entries(self, query_string):
        found_entries = None
        found_entries_study = None
        found_entries_page = None
        if query_string:

            entry_query_study = get_query(
                query_string,
                ['title', 'category', 'service', 'subject', 'industry', 'description', 'keywords', 'objective', ]
            )
            entry_query_page = get_query(query_string, ['title', 'url', 'category', 'keywords', ])

            found_entries_study = Study.objects.filter(entry_query_study).order_by('title')
            found_entries_page = Page.objects.filter(entry_query_page).order_by('title')

            found_entries = list(chain(found_entries_page, found_entries_study))

        return found_entries, found_entries_study, found_entries_page

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchResultsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        query_string = ''
        if ('q' in self.request.GET) and self.request.GET['q'].strip():
            query_string = self.request.GET['q']
        context["all_found_entries"], context["study"], context["page"] = self.find_entries(query_string)

        return context
```

I know it is just a way of accomplishing that. I'm just trying to give you an idea you could follow. I hope this can help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ListView`.

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    template_name = 'search-results.html'
    context_object_name = 'found_entries'

    def get_queryset(self):
        ...
        return list(chain(found_entries_page, found_entries_study))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchResultsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["query_string"] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        context["pages"] = ...
        context["studies"] = ...
        return context
```

The list returned by `get_queryset` will be available in the template as `found_entries`

Comment: How would I add found_entries and query_string to the context like I do in the FBV?  Other than that it's perfect so far.

Comment: Updated the answer. `found_entries` should already be available in the context. For `query_string`, you can also add it in `get_context_data`.